# Why my tree view is not loading in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-9, odoo

These following snippets are from my two XML files. I want to create a new tree view for the `res.partner` model.

```xml
<record id="distance_range_search_view_tree"model="ir.ui.view"> 
    <field name="name">distance_range_search_view_tree</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Contacts within Distance">
            <field name="display_name"/>
            <field name="country_id"/>
            <field name="city"/>
            <field name="state_id"/>
            <field name="zip"/>
            <field name="phone"/>
            <field name="distance"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="distance_range_search_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Account Proximity Search</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
    <field name='view_mode'>tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="distance_range_search_view_tree"/>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p>
           Here is the list of customers
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

And I use this method in my python file which returns the tree view:

```py
@api.multi
def distance_to_search1(self):
    #some other code
    return {
        'name': _('Contacts in this range'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'res.partner',
        'view_type': 'tree',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'view_id': self.env.ref('contact_geolocation.distance_range_search_view_tree').id,
        'domain': [('id', 'in', filtered_partner_ids)],
    }
```

Why is my tree view not loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<record id="distance_range_search_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Account Proximity Search</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
    <field name='view_type'>tree,form</field>
    <field name='view_mode'>tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="distance_range_search_view_tree"/>
    <field name="target">current</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p>
           Here is the list of customers
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

```py
@api.multi
def distance_to_search1(self):
    #some other code
    return {
        'name': _('Contacts in this range'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'res.partner',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'view_id': self.env.ref('contact_geolocation.distance_range_search_view_tree').id,
        'domain': [('id', 'in', filtered_partner_ids)],
    }
```

**Edit: I found this in the source code**

> For historical reasons, OpenERP has weird dealings in relation to
>   view_mode and the view_type attribute (on window actions):
>
> - one of the view modes is `tree`, which stands for both list views and tree views
> - the choice is made by checking `view_type`, which is either `form` for a list view or `tree` for an actual tree view.
>
> This methods simply folds the view_type into view_mode by adding a new
>   view mode `list` which is the result of the `tree` view_mode in
>   conjunction with the `form` view_type.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's so perfect.But please can you explain little bit why should we need to change the view_type=form?Thanks again

Comment: I don't know, Odoo works like that hahah. But if you want to make the research you can explore the base module where all the views are processed :)

Comment: And for the `view_mode` field you can write the order of the views you want to show (buttons in the upper right corner), i.e.: `kanban,tree,form`,

Comment: The other possible values for `view_type` are: `'view_type': 'list'`, `'view_type': 'tree,form'`

Comment: I got this from Odoo cook book "The window action's view_type attribute is mostly obsolete by now. The alternative to the default form is tree, which causes the groups lists to render a hierarchical tree. Don't confuse this attribute with the view_mode attribute used and explained earlier, which actually decides which types of views are used."